# Nullable of a grammar containing no epsilon transitions

Tags: parsing, grammar, nullable

I am asked in an assignment to provide the **nullable** set of the following Grammar:

```
E  -> E' E A
A  -> + | *
E  -> num
E' -> num
```

However, from my understanding the term **nullable** applies, if there exists som epsilon value on the right hand side of some production of the Grammar. But here I have no such epsilon terms.

Is it safe to assume that the above grammar does not hold any **nullable** values, such that:

```
nullable(E) = false
nullable(A) = false
nullable(E') = false
...
```

It just seems odd to compute the **nullable** values of a Grammar that does not contain any epsilon transitions in the Grammar productions.

I hope someone can perhabs provide me with a lending hand in case there is something I missed in my lectures on parsing, and Grammars in general. But from what I've read and understand, the above Grammar should not containg any **nullable** sets that hold the value **true**.

Comment: That's correct. If no production includes an empty right-hand side, then no non-terminal is nullable. (A right-hand side is not a "transition", though.) But you always have to do the computation, one way or another.

Comment: @rici Thanks for clarifying this for me. The above grammar is part of an expression that is gonna be transformed into a LL(1) parser, so the __nullable__ terms are need to compute the __first__ and __follow__ sets as well, which is why I guess its fine its false for all terms. It just seemed a bit counter intuitive at first.